# Responsive SVG Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I added a mask to my images which works properly in Chrome and Safari (via -webkit-mask-box-image).

I have added one for Firefox which works and shows up properly, like this:

```
<img src="assets/images/1.jpg" class="mask">
```

and the CSS for it is this:

```
.mask {
  clip-path: url(masks/mask.svg#mask);
}
```

Mask SVG is this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" width="718" height="718" viewBox="0 0 718 718">
  <clipPath id="mask">
  <path d="M718.004,358.999 C718.004,160.726 557.272,-0.007 358.998,-0.007 C160.725,-0.007 -0.007,160.726 -0.007,358.999 C-0.007,557.272 160.725,718.005 358.998,718.005 C557.272,718.005 718.004,557.272 718.004,358.999 Z"/>
  </clipPath>
</svg>
```

I tried following several tutorials and examples on making the mask responsive in Firefox (by setting width and height to 0 and by adding  maskUnits="objectBoundingBox") but i didnt had any luck.

Does somebody have any advice or suggestion on what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the url is correct? url(../masks/mask.svg#mask);

Comment: Yep, it is because the mask functions properly, it just isnt reponsive.
In this case i added "mask" because the original names are on my native language.

Comment: To be clear, are you including the non -webkit prefixed CSS for this or the -moz version (if needed)?

Comment: Rob, im not 100% sure that i understand you since this is the first time i am using SVG.
This is the full CSS for that:
.mask {
  -webkit-mask-box-image: url('masks/custom1.svg');
  mask-border: url('masks/custom1.svg');
  clip-path: url(masks/custom1.svg#custom1);
}

It works since it displays properly, but the only problem is responsiveness